# "Holmby hall" or "The Holmby Hall", does the hall have to be capital in either of them?

Tags: articles, capitalization

Holmby Hall is a landmark site in Los Angeles. The Wikipedia page doesn't use "the" before Holmby Hall, but has used the before The Fox Theatre.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The 'duplicate' is talking about uppercasing descriptive names, this is clearly talking about common words as part of a name.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the history of UCLA and the area adjacent to its campus, you'll find that a local development near the university was called *Holmby Hills*, so called by the original developer.  The building you're referring to, Holmby Hall, was named for the area nearby and was originally a dormitory for female students.  The appellation *hall* is a common one for university buildings, and indeed, many UCLA dormitories carry the word in their names.

*Holmby Hall* is a proper name, so both words must be capitalized.  The definite article is not required before personal proper names, and it's not required before building names that start with a personal proper name.